# Potential null pointer access. The variable may be null at this location. java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I know a lot of similar topics exist about this error but I tried some suggestions and my problem is still not saved.
I'm following this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B3gEbC37DAM&list=PL1A506B159E5BD13E&index=2

Here is my code:

```
public class JdbcDaoImpl {    
  public Circle getCircle(final int circleId) {
    Connection conn = null;

    try {
        String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
        Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby//localhost:1527//db");
        PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM circle where id= ?");
        ps.setInt(1, circleId);

        Circle circle = null;
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            circle = new Circle(circleId, rs.getString("name"));
        }
        rs.close();
        ps.close();
        return circle;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);

    } finally {
        try {
            conn.close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
        }

    }
  }
}
```

On "conn.close();" it says: Potential null pointer access. The variable may be null at this location.
And I have this error when i run the program: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

I tried solutions i saw on similar topics like this one:

```
if(conn!=null){
    conn.close();
}
```

but i still have errors.

Thank you in advance for your help !

Comment: What are the other errors?

Comment: what errors do you get when you put the `if` statement?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to explicitly load the driver (`Class.forName`), assuming you are using Java >= 1.6.

You can use try-with-resources to manage the AutoCloseable objects (`Connection`, `PreparedStatement`, and `ResultSet`), so your code can be written as:

```
public Circle getCircle(final int circleId) {
    try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby//localhost:1527//db");
         PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM circle where id= ?")){
      ps.setInt(1, circleId);

      Circle circle = null;
      try (ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery()) {
        if (rs.next()) {
          circle = new Circle(circleId, rs.getString("name"));
        }
      }
      return circle;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

This also guarantees all resources are closed properly, which solves a lot of issues that can arise because of resource leaks.

The problem was that getConnection could throw an Exception, leaving conn as null, which would cause a null pointer when you later tried to close it in the finally block.

Answer (score 0):

Finally Block is always executed while you are using try catch, where you can get a potential `NullPointerException` is when `conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby//localhost:1527//db");` throws `NullPointerException` which is caught by your `catch (Exception e)` and then finally block is starting to be executed where you do `conn.close()`, but your conn object is `NULL` which throws again `NullPointerException` which is not caught , cos you are catching `catch (SQLException e)`

Answer (score -1):

The reason why `conn` can be null is simple. If code executed before `conn` is asigned, ie before this code runs successfully:

```
String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver";
Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby//localhost:1527//db");
```

this code has to run successfully for conn not to be null, therefore you need a non-null check before calling `close()` on it.